# How to prepare a test for an Angular 7 Service that using @Inject() in the constructor

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have an Angular 7 Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClaimsService {
  lookupSplitter: KeyValuePair;

  constructor(
    @Inject(API_CLAIMS_BASE_URL) private apiClaimsBaseUrl: string,
    @Inject(LOOKUP_SPLIT_KEY_VALUE) lookupSplitKeyValueConst: KeyValuePair,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private log: LogService
  ) {
    this.lookupSplitter = lookupSplitKeyValueConst;
  }

  ...
}
```

I'm trying to create a unit test:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LogService } from '@app/core/logging/services/log.service';
import { instance, mock } from 'ts-mockito';
import { ClaimsService } from './claims.service';

describe('ClaimsService', () => {
  const mockLogService = mock(LogService);
  beforeEach(() =>
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [ClaimsService, { provide: LogService, useFactory: () => instance(mockLogService) }]
    })
  );

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: ClaimsService = TestBed.get(ClaimsService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Which is giving me the error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InjectionToken API_CLAIMS_BASE_URL]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken API_CLAIMS_BASE_URL]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken API_CLAIMS_BASE_URL!
```

I'm not sure how I set this up in the testbed. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collegue has helped me fix this:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { API_CLAIMS_BASE_URL, LOOKUP_SPLIT_KEY_VALUE } from '@app/app-injection-token';
import { LogService } from '@app/core/logging/services/log.service';
import { KeyValuePair } from '@app/core/models/key-value-pair';
import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
import { instance, mock } from 'ts-mockito';
import { ClaimsService } from './claims.service';

describe('ClaimsService', () => {
  const mockLogService = mock(LogService);
  const lookupSplitKeyValueConst: KeyValuePair = new KeyValuePair('key', 'value');
  beforeEach(() =>
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        ClaimsService,
        { provide: LogService, useFactory: () => instance(mockLogService) },
        { provide: API_CLAIMS_BASE_URL, useValue: environment.claimsServiceURL },
        { provide: LOOKUP_SPLIT_KEY_VALUE, useValue: lookupSplitKeyValueConst }
      ]
    })
  );

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: ClaimsService = TestBed.get(ClaimsService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```